# How to make ™ appear above the XYZ text?

Tags: html, css

How to make ™ a little above the XYZ text?

```html
<div>
<div style="display: inline-block;border: 1px solid red;">

XYZ

</div>

<div style="font-size:0.6em;border: 1px solid red;display: inline-block;">

&trade;

</div>
</div>
```

As you can see they are aligned side by side. I want the TM to be a little above the XYZ text.

Comment: Do you know HTML `<sup>TM</sup>`?

Comment: The phenomenon of "little above" is called Superscript and similarly "little below" is called Subscript. Just in case you don't know.

Comment: wow. how can I forget? Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Writing something a little above is called *superscript* and writing something a little below is called *subscript*.
In HTML you can use semantic elements `<sup>` or `<sub>`:

```html
<p>XYZ<sup>&trade;</sup></p>
<p>H<sub>2</sub>O</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always tweak [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to your liking:

```css
div div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div div:last-of-type {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  vertical-align: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>XYZ</div>
  <div>&trade;</div>
</div>
```

---

Note: this answer was written under the (possibly flawed) assumption that the markup in the question was part of the site layout and any solution should work around it—partly because not all but most of the issue is caused by the markup choice in the first place:

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">XYZ</div>
  <div style="font-size:0.6em;display: inline-block;">&trade;</div>
</div>

XYZ&trade;
```

For anyone googling here for a general solution to display ™ as superscript I recommend [`<sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) as [mx0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300886/13508). It may not be [entirely satisfactory](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements) from the semantic point of view but it's far superior to anything else :)

Comment: HTML has elements for this.

Comment: @connexo I guess you mean `<sup>`. I don't particularly enjoy its vague semantics, nor am I a fan of cluttering documents with presentation-oriented markup, and you may still need CSS to tweak its vertical-align anyway depending on the site layout. But it's indeed an alternative.

Comment: Imo it's still better than ending up in a soup of nested, meaningless `div`s. And how is `<div class="superscript">` less of a presentational piece of markup than `<sup>`?

Comment: @connexo Out curiosity, I checked the [HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements) and kind of reinforced my initial thoughts: "These elements must be used only to mark up typographical conventions with specific meanings, not for typographical presentation for presentation's sake. [...] In general, authors should use these elements **only if the absence of those elements would change the meaning of the content**.". (The `<div>`s are part of the question layout, not mine.)

Comment: Well spotted! Good job.